# Sometimes my client doesn't receive message's server

Tags: python, python-sockets

I'm using for the first time the module socket for python, I did my server and my client but there is a problem: sometimes my client doesn't receive the message from the server, because I guess that the server sent the message before that the client is listening. I thought to do something like that:

```
HEADER = 64  # Package bytes
FORMAT = 'utf-8'

while(response =! "received"):
    client1.send("hello")
    response = client1.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
```

This can't work because the function recv() wait until the package come.
Can somebody help me? Maybe there is a way for stop to recv after some seconds?
Thanks to who will answer me, and sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 0):

You can run it asynchronously using asyncore module

```
import asyncore
```

Then you create the class with it as a function, and run it using `asyncore.loop()`.

[More idea in docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/asyncore.html)